# Hazelcast not working after upgrade from 3.5 to 3.8

Tags: hazelcast

once I  upgraded the hazelcast from 3.5 to 3.8 the caching is not happening. And once I revert back to 3.5 it works fine when starting my project using 3.8 I am getting log as

```
Jul 02, 2018 10:02:00 AM com.hazelcast.config.XmlConfigLocator
INFO: Loading 'hazelcast.xml' from classpath.
```

and when i revert back to 3.5 the log shows

```
Jul 02, 2018 10:07:58 AM com.hazelcast.config.XmlConfigLocator
INFO: Loading 'hazelcast.xml' from classpath.
Jul 02, 2018 10:07:58 AM com.hazelcast.instance.DefaultAddressPicker
INFO: [LOCAL] [dev] [3.5] Prefer IPv4 stack is true.
Jul 02, 2018 10:07:58 AM com.hazelcast.instance.DefaultAddressPicker
INFO: [LOCAL] [dev] [3.5] Picked Address[172.30.66.245]:5701, using socket ServerSocket[addr=/172.30.66.245,localport=5701], bind any local is false
Jul 02, 2018 10:07:58 AM com.hazelcast.spi.OperationService
INFO: [172.30.66.245]:5701 [dev] [3.5] Backpressure is disabled
Jul 02, 2018 10:07:58 AM com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.classic.ClassicOperationExecutor
INFO: [172.30.66.245]:5701 [dev] [3.5] Starting with 2 generic operation threads and 4 partition operation threads.
Jul 02, 2018 10:07:58 AM com.hazelcast.system
INFO: [172.30.66.245]:5701 [dev] [3.5] Hazelcast 3.5 (20150617 - 4270dc6) starting at Address[172.30.66.245]:5701
Jul 02, 2018 10:07:58 AM com.hazelcast.system
INFO: [172.30.66.245]:5701 [dev] [3.5] Copyright (c) 2008-2015, Hazelcast, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
Jul 02, 2018 10:07:58 AM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService
INFO: [172.30.66.245]:5701 [dev] [3.5] Address[172.30.66.245]:5701 is STARTING
Jul 02, 2018 10:07:58 AM com.hazelcast.instance.Node
WARNING: [172.30.66.245]:5701 [dev] [3.5] No join method is enabled! Starting standalone.
Jul 02, 2018 10:07:58 AM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService
INFO: [172.30.66.245]:5701 [dev] [3.5] Address[172.30.66.245]:5701 is STARTED
Jul 02, 2018 10:07:58 AM com.hazelcast.internal.management.ManagementCenterService
INFO: [172.30.66.245]:5701 [dev] [3.5] Hazelcast will connect to Hazelcast Management Center on address: 
http://localhost:8080/mancenter
```

> Hazelcast.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hazelcast
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config
http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config/hazelcast-config-3.8.xsd "
    xmlns="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config " xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <network>
        <port>5701</port>
        <outbound-ports>
            <!-- Allowed port range when connecting to other nodes. 0 or * means use 
                system provided port. -->
            <ports>0</ports>
        </outbound-ports>
        <join>
            <multicast enabled="false" />
        </join>
    </network>

    <properties>
        <property name="hazelcast.health.monitoring.level">OFF</property>
        <property name="hazelcast.logging.type">log4j</property> 
    </properties>
</hazelcast>
```

Somebody, please help me with this.

Comment: What's in the logs when it fails ? What's in the `hazelcast.xml` file ? Can you post those two please. If you're upgrading, you may as well go to the very latest, not 3.8 but 3.10. And I see `No join method is enabled!` on 3.5, which usually isn't much use

Comment: I have updated the question with the hazelcast.xml file.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

The solution to a problem was that there was a typo in the configuration\

I had this

```
xmlns="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config "
```

The correct one should be

```
xmlns="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config"
```

Comment: Next time just check the answer that solved your problem and don't create a new answer yourself with the exact same content.

Answer (score 3):

I think your XML is not right.

You have

```
xmlns="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config "
```

This should be

```
xmlns="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config"
```

Ie. No trailing space.

Answer (score 0):

@Prajeesh, I used your config & successfully started a member:

```
INFO: [192.168.5.73]:5701 [dev] [3.8] [192.168.5.73]:5701 is STARTING
Jul 02, 2018 10:55:03 AM com.hazelcast.instance.Node
WARNING: [192.168.5.73]:5701 [dev] [3.8] No join method is enabled! Starting 
standalone.
Jul 02, 2018 10:55:03 AM com.hazelcast.system
INFO: [192.168.5.73]:5701 [dev] [3.8] Cluster version set to 3.8
Jul 02, 2018 10:55:03 AM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService
INFO: [192.168.5.73]:5701 [dev] [3.8] [192.168.5.73]:5701 is STARTED
```

I only removed the `log4j` property. I believe you have a log4j config in your classpath with uses a file so you're not seeing the logs. I used 3.8 & 3.10 and both worked fine.